# SQL Blob to Base 64 in Table for FileMaker

Tags: sql-server, base64, odbc, blob, filemaker

I have looked and found some instances there something similar is being done for websites etc....

I have a SQL table that I am accessing in FileMaker Pro (Through ESS) via an ODBC connection to the SQL database and I have everything I need except there is one field(LNL_BLOB) in one table (duo.MMOBJS) which is an image "(image, null)" which cannot be accessed via the ODBC connection.

What I am hopping to accomplish is find a way that when an image is placed in the field, it is ALSO converted to Base64 in another field in the same table.  Also, the database creator has a "View" (Foreign Concept to us Filemaker Developers) with this same data called "dbo.VW_BLOB_IMAGES" if that is helpful.

If there is a field with Base64 text, within FileMaker I can decode it to get the image.

What thoughts do you all have?  Is there and even better way?

NOTE:  I am using many tables and lots of the data in the app that I have made, this image is not the only reason I have created the ODBC connection.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHePw.png)

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIENl.png)

Comment: Since ESS does not support container fields, I think this is the only way. I did some research a while ago and my implementation was similar to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to get base64 out of SQL would be to trick the XML engine in SQL to convert your column to base64, then strip out the XML:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Q.Base64Data, 7, LEN(Q.Base64Data)-9)
FROM (SELECT
(
    SELECT LNL_BLOB AS B
    FROM duo.MMOBJS
    FOR XML raw('r'), BINARY BASE64
) AS [Base64Data]) AS [Q]
```

You'd probably want to add that to your select statement or a view, rather than add it to the table; but, you could write a trigger that would maintain the field using that definition.

Comment: Thank you!  I am going to look into this.  :-)